# How to group rows in Excel

Tags: excel

The situation is as below:

```
A B C 3  
A B C 4  
A B D 1  
A B E 2
```

How do I get to (in an automated manner)

```
A B C 7    
A B D 1  
A B E 2
```

Comment: Looks like a pivot table would solve your issue

Comment: I can't get it to format like the above

Comment: ok - I have to add - to get it automatically and exactly like your example, it would be a bit more complicated, than in my answer - because: you don't have a title row and it is not clear, if you want to replace your data or create the result somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SUBTOTAL` feature (ribbon-menu -> data-tab) or a pivot table to do this.

[SUBTOTALS miniHowTo](http://www.google.de/imgres?um=1&hl=de&client=firefox-a&sa=N&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&biw=1540&bih=809&tbm=isch&tbnid=AUpZ1AIabME3RM:&imgrefurl=http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-insert-subtotals-in-an-excel-2010-worksheet.html&docid=-B3NTZ89mGEzDM&imgurl=http://media.wiley.com/Lux/51/215251.image0.jpg&w=323&h=400&ei=H1-KUKy4KMfTsgaU3oDIBg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=587&vpy=337&dur=565&hovh=242&hovw=196&tx=106&ty=114&sig=110198793552409598277&page=1&tbnh=150&tbnw=121&start=0&ndsp=27&ved=1t:429,r:2,s:20,i:139)

And here a way with pivot tables:

[image]